# Twilio module email content via Python

Tags: python, twilio

I am trying to send a text message to myself using Python. Here is my code:

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

account_sid = ""
auth_token = ""
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(to="", from_="",
body=
"Some text here...\n"
"\n"
"Stats for this run through:"
"\n"
email_1
email_2
email_3
email_4
email_5
email_6
email_7
email_8
email_9
email_10
email_11
email_12
"\n"
"\n"
email_13
email_14
email_15                                 
)
```

In the above example email_1-email_15 are variables I have defined elsewhere. when I attempt to run this code though I get the following error:

```
    email_1
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am trying to get a multi line message and email_1-15 are made up of some text and a dynamic variable that were joined together into a string from a tuple.

Sample output should be:

```
Some text here...

Stats for this run through:

text_1: 1
text_2: 1
text_3: 1
text_4: 1
text_5: 1
text_6: 1
text_7: 1
text_8: 1
text_9: 1
text_10: 1
text_11: 1
text_12: 1
text_13: 1
text_14: 1
text_15: 1
```

Can anyone see what the issue is here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's invalid syntax in Python to have variable names inserted in your code that way. Something like this should work:

```
message = client.messages.create(to="", from_="",
body=
"Some text here...\n"
"\n"
"Stats for this run through:"
"\n" +
"\n".join([email_1, email_2, email_3, email_4, email_5, email_6, email_7,
    email_8, email_9, email_10, email_11, email_12, email_13, email_14,
    email_15])
 )
```

I would recommend very strongly that you define a list to contain the email variables, because it would make your code much simpler:

```
message = client.messages.create(to="", from_="",
body=
"Some text here...\n"
"\n"
"Stats for this run through:"
"\n" +
"\n".join(emails)
 )
```

Comment: I'm Megan from Twilio's Developer Community team. It would be awesome to send you a t-shirt for helping out in the StackOverflow community. Email mspeir@twilio.com for details.